# Why is SmartGWT overriding my CSS?

Tags: css, gwt, smartgwt, isomorphic

I’m tasked with developing a widget with buttons in SmartGWT (enterprise). The design calls for borders around the buttons. I’ve designed the CSS for this. However, SmartGWT insists on overriding my CSS border definition by filling in the “style” attribute on the generated TD. The docs for Canvas.setBorder actually say “This property applies the same border to all four sides of this component. Different per-side borders can be set in a CSS style and applied via styleName.” Clearly, it’s meant to be able to control border definitions with CSS.

I realize that I could just call setBorder with a concrete border definition, but I need to have different borders based on state (hover, down, etc.)

For example, the button label is “Review”. Here is the generated HTML:

```
<td class="controlButton" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none; text-align: center; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; vertical-align: middle;">
    <div style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; max-width: 100%;">
        <div id="isc_1G" overflow: hidden; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis; max-width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;">Review</div></div></td>
```

In my CSS, I have a class (controlButton) defined with a border, but the explicit border declaration in the “style” overrides it.

Here’s the code where I create the button:

```
Button button = new Button(“Review”);
button.setBaseStyle(“controlButton”);
button.setBorder("inherit");
button.setHeight(28);
```

I’ve also tried not calling setBorder, calling setBorder(null), and as above, setBorder(“inherit”). Nothing affects the inline style.

Here’s the CSS (omitting all of the state definitions for brevity):

```
.controlButton {
    background-color: #353535;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
    color: #d5d5d5;
}
```

In the browser’s programming mode, I can manually un-check the border definition in “inline style”, and my button looks correct using my class CSS.

By the way, I realize that I can use the !important modifier on the CSS, but there must be a way to make SmartGWT stop overriding without it.

The SmartGWT version is 4.0.5.
The GWT version is 2.7.0.

Comment: Did you try naming your css class to something different (less common)? Maybe `controlButton` is already being used by SmartGWT, and the name clash is what's causing your issues (which is something that has happened to me in the past with 'symptoms' similar to what your describe).

Comment: I tried a few different names. I don't think it's a CSS problem. The problem is that SmartGWT is injecting concrete style info into the "style" tag. I also tried manipulating that through the getElement, getContentElement, getOuterElement, etc. DOM APIs, with horrible results.

Comment: @Jamie, Can you show the file where this css is being loaded?